# Duplicate values SQL (MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to find duplicate records across 2 or more fields. But using this does not work in Access:

```
SELECT assay.depth_from, assay.au_gt
FROM assay 
GROUP BY depth_from, au_gt
HAVING count(*) >1;
```

Am I missing something? It does match up with various answers here so not sure what.

I just get a records with duplicate depth_from but the au_gt are not duplicate. Actually not all the depth_from are even all duplicated.

Comment: Sample data and desires results would help.  What do you mean by "duplicate records"?

Comment: Access even offers a built-in way to create a query to find duplicates, under _Create_ -> _Query Wizard_ -> _Find Duplicates Query Wizard_ which walks you through the process. If you're inexperienced with SQL you can just use that.

Comment: Seems obvious but never even thought of it as an option. Just used the wizard as it was for a quick check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible syntax issues with your SQL. First, you probably don't need to use the `assay.` prefix before your field names since you have specified which table you are selecting from, and this makes your reference to those fields in GROUP BY inconsistent. If you do use `assay.` in your SELECT statement use it in GROUP BY as well. Secondly, you should include `count(*)` in the SELECT statement. This is basically for the same reason- whatever you reference in GROUP BY and HAVING should be the column names you specified in SELECT. Try this:

`SELECT depth_from, au_gt, count(*)
FROM assay 
GROUP BY depth_from, au_gt
HAVING count(*) >1;`

Comment: Thanks. Access just adds in the table name but that didn't work.